# List of Scrollable Checkboxes in Processing

Tags: processing

I am a newbie to programming GUIs and Processing.  My questions is how can I get a list of checkboxes that I can scroll through?  What I want is exactly the list of countries on the right here (http://goo.gl/MIKHi4).

I looked through the ControlP5 library and was able to find Checkboxes, but I don't know how I can make a scrollable list of them.

Thank you.

Comment: maybe you can draw them in a dedicated PGraphic and use translate() to scroll...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had also been searching for this last week and hoping that there was a ready-for-use library for me to easily add the scrollable checkboxes to my application, but finally I had no luck. At last, what I did was implementing my own scrollable list of checkboxes.

Firstly, I added a ControlP5 slider as the scroll bar, and then at each frame, got value from the slider and draw the specific checkboxes based on that value.

Suppose that you have a list of 200 countries for the user to select. Then the code will be like:

```
ControlP5 cp5;
Slider scrollBar;
PFont fLabel;
int boxOver = -1; //Indicate mouse is over which checkbox
boolean[] boxSelected; //Checkbox selected or not
void setup() {
    size(1024, 800);
    colorMode(HSB, 360, 100, 100);
    cp5 = new ControlP5();
    scrollbar = cp5.addSlider("scrollbar")
         .setPosition(1005, 110)
         .setRange(0, 180)
         .setSize(15, 490)
         .setHandleSize(30)
         .setSliderMode(Slider.FLEXIBLE)
         .setValue(180); //Put handler at top because 0 value is at bottom of slider
    fLabel = createFont("Arial", 12, false);
    boxSelected = new boolean[200];
    for(int i=0;i<200;i++) {
        boxSelected[i] = false;
    }
}

void draw() {
    noFill();
    stroke(200, 255);
    rect(820, 110, 200, 490); //The outline of the scrollable box

    stroke(150, 255);
    int count = 0;

    //Suppose that you want to display 20 items each time
    for(int i=180-(int)scrollBar.getValue();i<180-(int)scrollBar.getValue()+20;i++) {
        if(boxOver < 0) {
            if(mouseX>=825 && mouseX<837 && mouseY >= 120+count*24 && mouseY <= 132+count*24) {
                boxOver = i;
                cursor(HAND);
            }
        }
        if(boxSelected[i]) {
            fill(50);  //If the box is selected, fill this box
        } else {
            fill(360);
        }
        rect(825, 120+count*24, 12, 12); //Draw the box

        //Draw the label text
        textFont(fLabel);
        fill(50);
        text(countries[i], 843, 132+count*24); //Suppose the country names are stored in countries[]

        count++;
    }
}

void mousePressed() {
    if(boxOver >=0) {
        boxSelected[boxOver] = !boxSelected[boxOver]; //Toggle selection
    }
}
```

Hope this helps you, or anyone who may encounter the same problem in the future.

Answer (score 0):

There is now an example in the experimental examples called [`ControlP5SliderList`](https://github.com/sojamo/controlp5/tree/master/examples/experimental/ControlP5SliderList)